# How to get number from link using xpath

Tags: xpath, href, contains

I am using this to get the number or all the href:

//chrome

```
$x("(//ul[@class='pagination']//li/a[contains(.,'Seguinte')]/@href)");
```

The page has this:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="http://www.website.com/fornecedores--2">Seguinte</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want the text of href "`http://www.website.com/fornecedores--2`".

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: well... what is wrong?

Comment: `string(//ul[@class='pagination']//li/a[contains(.,'Seguinte')]/@href)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`substring-after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after) to get the part of the `href` attribute after the `--`:

```
substring-after(//ul[@class='pagination']//li/a[contains(.,'Seguinte')]/@href, '--')
```